# Wordpress LOOP [Only title and data]

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i have a wordpress and i want to use a php LOOP to cicle through my posts so i can get all my posts, the problem is that i only want the title of the post, the content of it and the date...

```
<?php 
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
         get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
         echo "<br/><br/>";
     endwhile; 
?>
```

This is a generic code for looping i tryed searching over the `get_post_format()` function so i can only get what i need but no sucess can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_title()`, `the_date()`, and `the_content()` within the loop.

```
the_title(); //displays post title
the_content(); //displays post content
the_date(); //displays post date
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple call `the_title(),the_content(),the_date()` in the loop

```
<?php 
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
         the_title();
         the_content();
         the_date();
         the_time('F jS, Y');
     endwhile; 
?>
```

[**The_Loop_in_Action**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action)

Answer (score 0):

For normal posts [get_post_format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format) returns boolean `FALSE`. [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) basically joins it's string parameters with '-' and includes the template with the resulting name. If `get_post_format()` is `FALSE` then it'll include `content.php`. I'd replace `get_post_format()` with a custom string and create `content-something.php` as a copy of `content.php`, editing it the way you need to.